# merge ManagedobjectContext in multi threads

Tags: iphone, multithreading, core-data, nsnotificationcenter

My app have main thread which run every ten second and read data from core data and second thread to fetch data from server and load into coredata. after reading some example and also apple document I am still not sure the way i merge is correct:
1. i create new managedObjectContext for each save in database and set it to (single PersistentStore in appp delegate) . 
2. have this code when i initate the class for loading data in user view:

```
NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]; 
        [nc addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(mergeChanges:)
                   name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                 object:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];

-(void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification *)notification
{    
    NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];      
    // Merge changes into the main context on the main thread
    [mainContext performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:)
                                  withObject:notification
                               waitUntilDone:YES];  
}
```

3- read data from coredata from main context

I am wondering if this is correct. 
thanks